# Problem getting value in Spring Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am facing a problem trying to get from a post the values:

Here is my HTML

```
            <td> 
                <form class="form-inline" action="/infopedidos" th:action="@{/infopedidos}" th:object="${newRider}" method="post">

                    <select> 
                        <option th:each="riders: ${TodosLosRiders}" th:value="${riders.getRider_id()}" th:text="${riders.getRemail()}">
                        </option>                       
                    </select>

                    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Asignar rider</button>

                </form>
            </td>
```

And I am trying to get in a post the value "riders.getRider_id()"

Here is my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/infopedidos")
        public String UsuariosIntervaloSubmit(Model model, @ModelAttribute riders newRider, @RequestParam(value="$riders.getRider_id()}") String param) throws ParseException {
```

And the error that I have is the next:

```
Required String parameter 'riders.getRider_id()' is not present
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'riders.getRider_id()' is not present
```

Can you help me guys? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you reading this : https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc

Your form is currently sending **only** your 'newRider' object as a @ModelAttribute. But your select tag is not pointing to any field in your object. That means you are not changing the object in your form inputs. Only sending it. You should include 'th:field' attr to your select tag if you want to edit your 'newRider' object and send it via post.

```
<select th:field="*{<somefield>}">
```

Your Controller:

```
 @PostMapping("/infopedidos")
    public String UsuariosIntervaloSubmit(Model model, @ModelAttribute riders newRider ) throws ParseException {
```

But if you want to send data of your select option as a request parameter, you have to add name to your select tag.

```
<select th:name="<paramName>">
```

Your controller:

```
@PostMapping("/infopedidos")
    public String UsuariosIntervaloSubmit(Model model, @ModelAttribute riders newRider, @RequestParam(value="<paramName>") String param) throws ParseException {
```

form:

```
<form th:action="@{/<mapping>}" method="post">
            <select class="form-control" name="<paramName>">
                <option th:each="obj : ${objList}"
                        th:value="${obj.field}" th:text="${obj.field2}"></option>
            </select>
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping
public String func(@RequestParam("<paramName>") String param, Model model) {
     ** Your Code Here **
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, helps a lot to understand it. The problem that I have is now         public String UsuariosIntervaloSubmit(Model model, @ModelAttribute riders newRider, @RequestParam(value="$riders.getRider_id()}") String param) throws ParseException {
with this error : Required String parameter 'riders.getRider_id()' is not present

Comment: Delete 'th:object' from your form. And give a valid name to your parameter. @RequestParameter("<paramName>") and <select th:name="<paramName>"> <paramName> is only the name of your parameter for your mapping to catch it.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks a lot! But what If I want to get more than 1 value, I mean for example obj.field , obj.field2 and ofbj.field3. Thanks!

Comment: You can send multiple request parameters the way i show you. But you can also  send a object from form and catch it in your mapping implementation via @ModelAttiribute. The link I sent you in my answer explains it really well. https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc#input